# Native SQL query for an Hibernate entity using @Formula results in NullPointerException

Tags: hibernate, formula, native-sql

I've got an simple Hibernate entity for which I use the @Formula annotion:

```
    @Id
private Long id;

private String name;

@Formula("(select count(f.*) from foo f where f.id = id)")
private long bar;
```

When I try to load an entity with a native SQL Query:

```
EM.createNativeQuery("SELECT f.*, count(something) as bar FROM foo f WHERE f.name = '...'", Entity.class)
```

I get an NullPointerException:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.intern(DefaultEntityAliases.java:193)
at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.getSuffixedPropertyAliases(DefaultEntityAliases.java:151)
at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.determinePropertyAliases(DefaultEntityAliases.java:93)
at org.hibernate.loader.DefaultEntityAliases.<init>(DefaultEntityAliases.java:65)
at org.hibernate.loader.ColumnEntityAliases.<init>(ColumnEntityAliases.java:45)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.generateCustomReturns(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:197)
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery.<init>(SQLCustomQuery.java:152)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.<init>(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:67)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:140)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:160)
at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:179)
at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:236)
```

When I remove the @Formula attribute all works fine.

I found this bug report: [BugReport](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2536). But for me it's not clear how to solve my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, this seems to be the problem reported in [HHH-2225](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2225) (that [HHH-2536](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2536) duplicates). Unfortunately, the issue is not fixed and I'm afraid you'll have to either use HQL or submit a patch (you can start with voting on the issue but I wouldn't expect a fast resolution given that this issue is almost four years old).

Comment: Years later, I still stumble upon this bug :(

Comment: I have the same issue with Hibernate 5.4.3.Final

Answer (score 0):

We could use currentSession.createQuery() instead of currentSession.createSQLQuery(). The query will be slightly different.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-subqueries

Answer (score 0):

Simply way , don't use createNativeQuery , just use createQuery ..
or make a transiant with getter convat

Comment: Provide some examples please