# The nativequery result got nullpointerexception I don't know why

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

This is the query that got error from Shop repository

```
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = " select * from shop sh where sh.id in (select * from (select fs.shop_id from follow_shop fs group by fs.shop_id order by count(fs.shop_id ) desc limit :param) AS pp) order by bellscore desc")
    Page<Shop> findPopularTop3Shop(@Param("param")Long param, Pageable pageable);
```

The compare native query in mysql is

```
select * from shop where id in (select * from (select fs.shop_id from follow_shop fs group by fs.shop_id order by count(fs.shop_id ) desc limit 3) AS pp) order by bellscore desc
```

This is Shop Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Table(name ="shop")
//@Document(indexName ="shop") 
public class Shop extends BaseTimeEntity { 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String image;

    private Long bellscore;

    private BigDecimal latitude;

    private BigDecimal longitude;

    private String address;

    private String runtime;

    private Timestamp openTime;

    private Timestamp closeTime;


    @Formula("(select count(*) from follow_shop where follow_shop.shop_id=id)")
    private int follower;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shopId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ShopMenu> shopId = new ArrayList<>();


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<FollowShop> followShops = new ArrayList<>();


    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shopId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Reservation> reservationShop = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "shop")
    private List<Feed> feedList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Builder
    public Shop (
            Long id,
            String name,
            String image,
            Long bellscore,
            BigDecimal latitude,
            BigDecimal longitude,
            String address,
            String runtime,
            int follower,
            Timestamp openTime,
            Timestamp closeTime
    ) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.image = image;
        this.bellscore = bellscore;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.address = address;
        this.runtime = runtime;
        this.follower = follower;
        this.openTime = openTime;
        this.closeTime = closeTime;
    }
}
```

This is follow_shop entity

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class FollowShop  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private User user;

    @JoinColumn(name = "shop_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Shop shop;

    public FollowShop(User userId, Shop shopId) {
        this.user = userId;
        this.shop = shopId;
    }

    public static FollowShop create(User user, Shop shop) {
        return new FollowShop(user, shop);
    }
}
```

And this is error log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.String$CaseInsensitiveComparator.compare(String.java:1218) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntryUsingComparator(TreeMap.java:374) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.getEntry(TreeMap.java:343) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:277) ~[na:na]
    at com.mysql.cj.result.DefaultColumnDefinition.findColumn(DefaultColumnDefinition.java:182) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:578) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:843) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.27.jar:8.0.27]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getInt(HikariProxyResultSet.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1887) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1811) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1784) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1624) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:748) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1047) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:338) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1204) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.3.Final.jar:5.6.3.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:179) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.0.jar:2.6.0]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.findPopularTop3Shop(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at malangcute.bellytime.bellytimeCustomer.shop.service.ShopService.getTop3ShopList(ShopService.java:74) ~[classes/:na]
    at malangcute.bellytime.bellytimeCustomer.shop.service.ShopService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fe250d4f.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698) ~[spring-aop-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at malangcute.bellytime.bellytimeCustomer.shop.service.ShopService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ad354fe.getTop3ShopList(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at malangcute.bellytime.bellytimeCustomer.shop.controller.ShopController.getTop3PopularShopList(ShopController.java:24) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at malangcute.bellytime.bellytimeCustomer.global.auth.TokenAuthentication.doFilterInternal(TokenAuthentication.java:99) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at malangcute.bellytime.bellytimeCustomer.global.auth.TokenAuthentication.doFilterInternal(TokenAuthentication.java:99) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at malangcute.bellytime.bellytimeCustomer.global.auth.JWTExceptionFilter.doFilterInternal(JWTExceptionFilter.java:62) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:219) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:213) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:178) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.14.jar:5.3.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

I don't know the reason because other jpa query in Shop repository it works!
except that native query
Am I wrote wrong?
If so please let me know right query
I want to got 3 data from follow table which have the most counted in the table and get shop id from follow table find those 3 shop id from shop table and return that result.

Thank you

Comment: Seems odd that you would wrap the "select fs.shop_id" results in a near identical select * query. The problem though seems to be with Hibernate interpreting the results. You might try a simple "Select s from Shop s" and see what SQL it generates - chances are it might expect some joins and other table fields in there that you've not represented in your native SQL query - like the follower formula.

Comment: PS I'm not sure how hibernate handles formula fields in queries, but your query is really something like "select s from Shop s order by s.follower", and then just use pagination/JPA max results to limit the results to the top 3. I'd recommend strongly you stay away from native queries if and where possible; define it once in one location to avoid maintenance issues when it may need to change (like for performance reasons).

Comment: @Chris I checked about your opinion and I found that formula query in entity class makes error about native query in shop jpa repository so I deleted it then works fine. I'm still find out about that problem but I 'm very glad about that. Thank you

Comment: This was already reported here! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3331529/native-sql-query-for-an-hibernate-entity-using-formula-results-in-nullpointerex

Answer (score 1):

You need to check columns

in your DB are equal to columns in entity
because

if they are not equal
you can't call `select *`
it will create mapping issue for JPA

Answer (score 0):

i just noticed something wrong and i dont know whether a typo or not:

```
select * from shop where id in 
(
select * from ???//where table name ?
(select fs.shop_id from follow_shop fs group by fs.shop_id order by 
 count(fs.shop_id ) desc limit 3) AS pp
) 
order by bellscore desc
```